# 英語が残っている：コメントの削除メニュー (モバイル版)

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

モバイル版でアクセスした際、自身のコメントに表示される削除メニューが英語の「delete」になっています。
https://ja.traducir.win/ で検索して出てくる単純な「delete」は「削除」に翻訳されているので、どこか別の箇所で残っているものと思われます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEチームによって、「削除」と変更されました。

[image]