# 新モデレーター就任のお知らせ：cubick！

Tags: 討議, モデレーション

ここ数ヶ月の間、スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版（メタを含む）のトラフィックが急上昇しました。entoはスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版公開当初から多大な貢献をもたらしてくれましたが個人的な理由でモデレーターを退任することになり、[スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版モデレーターチーム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) はコミュニティを円滑に進めるためにはもう一人のモデレーターが必要であるという結論に至りました。

私たちが[“暫定”モデレーター](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2692/%E6%9A%AB%E5%AE%9A%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC)の候補者を考えたとき、「@cubickをモデレーターに」という推薦には即座に皆の同意を得ることができました。そしてこの度オファーが受諾され、@cubickを新モデレーターとして発表できることを大変嬉しく思います！

さぁ、皆で@cubickを歓迎しましょう！

> **cubickさんとは？**
>
> プログラミングに触れたきっかけは、自分で作成したHPに「自作のカウンターを設置したい！」から始まってCGI(Perl)を動かすためにLinuxやwebサーバもいじり始めたのを機に、現在はLinuxのインフラ周りを管理するお仕事をしております。自分でプログラムを書く機会は減りましたが、最近はGitHubにて日本語翻訳のコントリビュートを行ったりしています。
>
> スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版の登録自体は2015年頃にしていたようなのですが、しばらくは使い方が分からず放ったらかしになっていました。初めて投稿した質問がたまたま注目してもらったのをきっかけに、SOの仕組みを少しずつ理解していく過程で頻繁に利用するようになりました。
>
> モデレーターになるにあたっては、be nice.(親切であれ)を忘れずに、質問者と回答者のお互いが気持ちよく学び会える場のお手伝いができればと思います。
>
> 日本語版コミュニティーのみなさん、スタック・オーバーフローは魅力的なサイトだけどまだまだ利用者が増える余地はあると思うので、みんなで少しずつ知識の輪を広げていきましょう。
>
> [image: cubick]

私たちは@cubickがモデレーターチームに加わることによって日本語版コミュニティがさらに活発になり、より良い方向へ向かうことができると信じています。

スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版の新しいモデレーターとして@cubickを応援してください！

---

A lot of thanks for the translation and all communications to @aki!

Comment: @ento さん、これまでありがとうございました！

Answer (score 11):

cubick さんを歓迎します！　cubick さんはメインサイトにおいて種々の投稿や投票をしてくださっているだけでなく、メタサイトにおいても議論に参加してくださっています。また、サイトの翻訳作業も行ってくださっており、スタック・オーバーフローをより良い場所にしてくださっています。たとえば最近だとモバイル版での翻訳バグを[報告](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2861/19110)してくださいました (バグを報告してくださる人がいるって、とても良いことですよね :)。

cubick さんが暫定モデレーターになって頂けたことで、このサイトはもっともっと良くなっていくと思います。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いいたします <(_ _)>

P.S. 個人的にはアイコンの色合いが好きです。

Answer (score 3):

cubickさん、ウェルカムなのです！よろしくおねがいします！